# Setting values of DOM items before page load in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, pageload, setvalue

I have a form and I am setting values to boxes(textbox, selectbox, radiobox)  on page load like shown below.

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#text").val(\''.$_GET['q'].'\');
   $("#category").val(\''.$_GET['cat'].'\');
});
</script>
```

But the main problem is that first page loads with empty boxes and after a second or sometimes more than a second it loads the values to boxes. How can I make to show page after all boxes're set the values? This must be in jquery.

P.S. Please don't offer me php solutions. If it is possible only jquery solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why must it be in jQuery, why can't you set the values in plain javascript, or even better directly in the HTML as I assume $_GET refers to PHP variables, and the method you are using for setting those values seem completely uneccessary?

```
<input type="text" value="$_GET['q']" id="text" />
```

or in plain js placed right after the elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('test').value = $_GET['q'];
</script>
```

skipped some strange escaping and concentanation, and did'nt care much about all the different quotes, you'll have to figure those out yourself, just to show how I'd do it?

jQuery waits until the DOM and everything in it is loaded, so you already have the jQuery solution. That means the jQuery code will always be executed later than just setting the values directly, or even using plain javascript as soon as the elements are available etc.

If you really don't care about user experience or loading times at all, you could always just set the `body` tag to `display:none` in your css and use `$('body').show();` right after you set the values in your jQuery script, that's a jQuery solution, but it's a bad one!

Comment: Thanks first of all. I understand you, I know that setting with php is carefree solution. But the form is very dynamic and most of items loads on change of another box and all this have been done in jquery before me. I cannot see all boxes in php because some of them are generated by jquery. I just want to show the page after setting all values.

Comment: Yes, body display solution is bad. What else you can suggest me? Have I explained the situation properly?

Comment: Well, I think the question is ok, but the best solution IMO is to find some way to set those PHP values from $_GET directly to the elements. You're setting them on document.ready already, and not on some specific event, so it would be just the same to set them directly in PHP where the form is generated, just a little more work to figure out exactly where to insert them if the form is complicated, but it is by far the best solution, and the only one that will populate the form on page load as all javascript solutions will have to insert them after the fact.